# Functional equation over $f(x) = \int_0^{ax}f(t)dt + g(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Let $a\in(-1,1)$ and $g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$.

Let $S(a, g)$ the set of all f such that :
$$f(x) = \int_0^{ax}f(t)dt + g(x)$$

The first part was to show that :
$$S(a, 0) = \{0_{\mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R}} \}$$
Which I did using Taylor-Lagrange inequality and other things.

The second part is deducting from that that $S(a, g)$ have at most 1 element. I don't know what to start with, could you give me some hints,  please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still thinking about the first part.

But to prove the second part, suppose $f_1,f_2\in S(a,g)$. Then 
$$f_i(x)=\int_0^{ax}f_i(t)dt+g(x)\mbox{ for }i=1,2.$$
Subtract the first equation by the second one, we get 
$$f_1(x)-f_2(x)=\int_0^{ax}f_1(t)-f_2(t)dt.$$
That is to say, $f_1-f_2\in  S(a,0)$. Using the first part that $S(a, 0) = \{0_{\mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R}} \}$, we have 
$f_1=f_2$. This implies that $S(a,g)$ can have at most one element.